# Optimizing MSSQL for High Volume Single Record Inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a C# application that receives a file each day with ~35,000,000 rows. It opens the file, parses each record individually, formats some of the fields and then inserts one record at a time into a table. It's really slow, which is expected, but I've been asked to optimize it.

I have instructed that that any optimizations must be contained to SQL only. i.e., there can be no changes to the process or the C# code. I'm trying tom come up with ideas on how I can speed up this process while being limited to SQL modifications only. I have a couple of ideas I want to try but I'd also like feedback from anyone who has found themselves in this situation before.

Ideas:
1. Create a clustered index on the table so the insert always occurs at the tale end of the file. The records in the file are ordered by date/time and the current table has no clustered index so this seems like a valid approach.

2. Somehow reduce the logging overheard. This data is volatile in nature so it's not a big deal to be able to rollback. Even if the process blew up halfway through, they would just restart it.
3. Change the isolation level. Perhaps there is an isolation level that is more suited for sequential single-record inserts.
4. Reduce connection time. The C# app is opening/closing a connection for each insert. We can't change the C# code though so perhaps there is a trick to reducing overhead/time to make a connection.

I appreciate anyone taking the time to read my post and throw out any ideas they feel would be worth it.

Thanks,
Dean

Comment: [`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) is probably the best solution and/or custom SSIS package.

Comment: To reduce the logging overhead, if the app is using single-statement transactions consider delayed durability.

Comment: Drop all indexes except for the clustered index mentioned in #1. Nothing you can do to reduce logging overhead aside from delayed durability as David mentioned and hardware (e.g. log file on SSD). Re #3, the default READ_COMMITTED isolation level will perform best. The default connection pooling will mitigate open/close overhead; other connection management methods require code changes. These changes will provide only minor performance improvements. You'll get orders of magnitude gains (millions per minute instead of thousands) with SqlBulkCopy or table-valued parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following -- if possible.

1. Load the data into a staging table.
2. Do the transformations in SQL.
3. Bulk insert the data into the final table.

The second suggestion would be:

1. Modify the C# code to write the data into a file.
2. Bulk insert the file, either into a staging table or the final table.

Unfortunately, your problem is 35 million round trips from C# to the database.  I doubt there is any database optimization that can fix that performance problem.  In other words, you need to change the C# code to fix the performance issue.  Anything else is probably just a waste of your time.

You can minimize logging either by using simple recovery or writing to a temporary table.  Either of those might help.  However, consider the second option, because it would be a minor change to the C# code and could result in big improvements.

Or, if you have to do the best in a really bad situation:

- Run the C# code and database on the same server.  Be sure it has lots of processors.
- Attach lots of SSD or memory for the database (if you are not already using it).
- Load the data into table spaces that are only on SSD or in memory.
- Copy the data from the local database to the remote one.

Comment: Although I completely agree with your suggestions, I can't modify the process or the code.

Comment: I did, however, move the LDF to a separate drive on the server and throughput has improved at least 5 fold.